# Tools for programming tutorials?

Tags: language-agnostic

I engage in lot of training sessions and I would like to create video tutorials of all my sessions so that I can distribute it. What are the best Windows-based tools to add my PowerPoint slides, notes, voice and video (tutorials of code I write) and compile them into one video?

Comment: Sorry missed it!! For windows!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp), if you're on Windows.

Comment: Got me exactly 1 second before i posted! :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting a really awesome suite!

Answer (score 5):

We are using Camtasia (http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) but I've heard that Adobe's Captivate (http://www.adobe.com/products/captivate/) is way better. Both solutions are commercial.

If you are looking for a free alternative, Camstudio(http://camstudio.org/) is pretty good, although it lacks a lot of  features.

Comment: it's a shame that captivate doesnt come with CS4 master collection.

Comment: Thanks +1 :) Its sad that I cannnot mark two answers as accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

[CamTasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) (TechSmith.com) integrates with PowerPoint, has an excellent editor and is very powerful.  If you're spending more than a few hours on screencasts, get CamTasia.  It can integrate a webcam too and export SCORM for e-learning.

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is gpl, fine for simple screencasts, lacks an editor and has problem with audio/video synchronisation after 10s of minutes of recording (CamTasia has no synch problems)

[HyperCam](http://www.hyperionics.com/hc/) is a no-frills shareware recorder, similar to CamStudio, no synch bugs, but no editor either.  The author is responsive to bugs, I used it a few yrs back, it does fine for basic recordings.

[VirtualDubMod](http://virtualdubmod.sourceforge.net/) is a gpl video editor, it is clunky but will give you some editing+merging power if you're using CamStudio

I'd suggest getting a reasonable mic (£40UK on a usb mic should do fine), avoid 3.5mm analogue jack mics as motherboard electrical noise will come through in your recording.

[ShowMeDo.com](http://showmedo.com/) (disclosure: I'm a co-founder) hosts 800 open-source tutorial screencasts made by >100 open source authors.  If you want diverse examples of presenting presentation+programming material, you'll find *many* examples and a friendly community here.

I'm a professional screencaster with 4 yrs experience.  I've been gathering various articles and interviews (disclosure: some interviews are with me) that should give you further background, they cover open-source tutorials, product demos, how-tos etc:

[blog.procasts.co.uk/2009/01/screencaster-interviews-and-articles/](http://blog.procasts.co.uk/2009/01/screencaster-interviews-and-articles/)

Comment: I would +10 this if I could.  Great overview of the existing tools, and thanks for introducing us to ShowMeDo.

Answer (score 2):

Techsmith Camtasia. Supreme Screen/voice recorder with extensive deployment option (ie. as flash, avi, etc..)